# Seudas Bris on a pushed-off fast

Tags: halacha, fast-days, brit-milah, meal-seudah

When Tisha B'Av is pushed off from Shabbos to Sunday the "bal habris" may eat a seudah (meal).

A few questions. (I have no other background information to give and I'm asking because simply a lack of knowledge.)

1. Who is the bal habris in regards to eating? Is it the father of the son only? Or the sandek and mohel as well? May anyone else eat?
2. Is this true for other fasts, not just Tisha b'Av that are pushed off? (For example this year Tzom Gedelyah will be pushed off from Shabbos to Sunday.)
3. Is one required to have a seudah at this time or is it simply permitted in such a situation if one would like to have seudah?
4. Although [poskim](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1428) do say that one may have a seudah, does anyone know if there is a custom perhaps to be stringent and not eat? (Whether it be in the case of Tisha B'Av that was pushed off or by any other fast that this might apply to.)

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5758/devarim.html. Youre

Answer (score 2):

1. [Mishnah Berurah 559:36](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.559.36?lang=bi) rules that *ba'al brit* includes the father and mother of the child, as well as the *mohel* and *sandek*, but no other honorees (e.g. *kvatter*) and certainly not other guests.

2. [Mishnah Berurah 559:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.559.35?lang=bi) notes that on other fast days **which are not postponed**, a *ba'al brit* must complete the fast. The implication is that if they are postponed, a *ba'al brit* may eat, just like on a postponed *tish'ah b'av*.

3. & 4. [Aruch HaShuhlchan 559:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.559.9?lang=bi) writes that the no-one in his locale had a meal during a postponed *tish'ah b'av*. Instead, the meal was held at night following the fast. He writes that one should adhere to this custom, on all postponed fasts, not just *tish'ah b'av*.

The implication of this ruling is clearly that there is no obligation to have a meal during the day.

Comment: The AhS could also be interpreted as there is an obligation to have a mea accd to the Shuchan Arukhl, but since there are other opinions (of most Rishonim) that prohibit it outright, Shev veAl Taaseh is preferred